# Please help me with this matrices question

Tags: matrices

I was trying to solve (prove) these matrices and wanted to make sure I got the proof correctly

> If $A$ is symmetric orthogonal matrix then $A^2 = I$

and

> If $B = A A^T$ then $B$ is symmetric

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

- If $A$ is symmetric, then $A = A^T$, so that
  $$A^2 = A A^T = ...?$$
- If $B = A A^{T}$, then $$B^T = \left( A A^T\right)^T = \left(A^T\right)^T A^T = ...?$$

Comment: Thank you so much T.Bongers.